# Meaning of symbol similar to $\not >$ in front of a matrix

Tags: notation, quaternions

I found the following symbol in a paper about rotations using quaternions:
[image: symbol]

The paragraph appears at the beginning of page 635 in [Closed-form solution of absolute orientation using unit quaternions](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/papers/Absolute_Orientation.pdf) by Berthold K. P. Horn.

Does it have any special meaning? What does it refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After revising the paper once and again, my conclusion is that  $\not >\mathbb{R}_{l,i}$ and $\bar{\mathbb{R}}_{l,i}$ (last matrix in page 634) are the same. Thus it seems to be just a matter of notation; maybe some Latex problem due to inline math coding.

Comment: I agree, it can be a LaTeX typo, these prefix commands like ``\not`` or ``\bar`` can be tricky from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

If it were $A \not\gt B$, it probably means "not strictly positive", which for a matrix is NOT equivalent to $\leq$ (for a real number, $x \not\gt 0 \leftrightarrow x \leq 0$).
So $A \not\gt B$ means $A - B$ is **not** a positive definite (p.d.) matrix.

But on the paper you cited, I have no idea what it could mean, sorry.